# Is there any way to get better error messages in a node project built with webpack?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I have a react/redux/webpack project that I want to build for server side rendering. When I run it I get some error messages but they all say stuff like `webpack-internal:///95:951:4`

Example output:

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at Reducer.eval (webpack-internal:///95:951:4)
    at Object.eval [as dispatch] (webpack-internal:///207:11:18)
    at Actions.dispatch (webpack-internal:///203:52:21)
    at new OrderForm (webpack-internal:///168:65:12)
    at resolve (webpack-internal:///212:2100:14)
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render (webpack-internal:///212:2260:22)
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (webpack-internal:///212:2234:19)
    at Object.renderToString (webpack-internal:///212:2501:25)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///173:50:40)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///173:60:6)
```

It would be neat with the source file names.

Comment: Turn on source mapping in your Webpack config.

Comment: Cool, I did not realise source-maps would work in node but they did using devtool: 'source-map' in the webpack config and removing the -d option when compiling.